# Sent mail using smtp not working when deployed in microsoft windows azure c# asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, smtp, azure-web-app-service

I've been trying unsuccessfully to get an email in my Azure Website. I can get it working on my localhost using either the GMail SMTP settings. However when deployed to my windows azure website ,even on my localhost IIS it doesn't work. none mail being sent or received!!! there is my code in web.config:

```
<appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="Smtp_Server" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
        <add key="Smtp_Port" value="587" />
        <add key="Smtp_UserName" value="*****" />
        <add key="Smtp_Password" value="***" />
        <add key="Smtp_bSSLConnection" value="True" />
        <add key="ActiveSendMail" value="False" />
        <add key="SecurityKey" value="****" />
      </appSettings>
```

When i was searching i found a link that told me that "SMTP is not supported by Azure  : http://www.postseek.com/meta/488719217d716a4fc35c7d6f336e263c" I want to know is that correct??
Would i use another sent mail server?

Answer (score 1):

SMTP probably isn't supported.

You could us [Mandrill](https://mandrillapp.com/) they have an api that you can use to send email that works over http, so you don't need to worry about smtp.

Comment: ,Are you sure SMTP isn't supported?

Comment: I'm not sure but it is quite normal for hosting services to block SMTP as it is often used to send spam

Comment: i used EasendMail as the dll to send mail but this class doesn't support DEFAULTCREDENTIAL proprety to configure the sent mail via Windows Azure. Is there a way to do that??? Must i abandant EasendMail  and use SendGrid

Answer (score 0):

Even though I logged in to my Gmail account and "white listed" my C# code hosted in Azure, Gmail kept on blocking my emails.

I opted instead to use Hotmail SMTP and use that account instead of Gmail SMTP.

ASP.NET 5 example:

```
public class AuthMessageSender : IEmailSender, ISmsSender <br/>
{ <br/>
    public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message) <br/>
    { <br/>
        var mailMessage = new MailMessage(email, email, subject, message); <br/>
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder(); <br/>
        var config = builder.Build(); <br/>
        var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 587) <br/>
        { <br/>
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("jon@doe.com", "password"),
            EnableSsl = true <br/>
        };<br/>
        client.Send(email, "ToAddress@gmail.com", subject, message); <br/>
        return Task.FromResult(0); <br/>
    } <br/>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your Gmail account. Allow less secure app to access third party
2. When allow less secure app the email will sent successfully on local but not sent after deployed to live server.
3. When you try to send email first time from live server then after first attempt to
   send email from live server go to your Gmail Account again and check activity and
   verify that its attempt is identify.
4. After verify your attempt, the smtp server will sent email successfully from your
   live server.

Comment: just curious how gmail account connected to smpt on azure ?